# Problema pago tarjeta de credito

Tags: wordpress, mercadopago, wordpress-plugin

Estamos teniendo problemas con el plugin de MP para wordpress  / Woocommerce.

Los usuarios no pueden finalizar la compra con el checkout básico usando tarjeta de credito. 
Si pueden hacerlo con debito o si el cliente le comparte el link generado desde mp con debito o credito.

El problema surge en el flujo desde la web al checkout en la pagina de MP.

Adjunto fracción del log de wp

```html
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/index.php:0
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   2. require() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/index.php:17
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   3. wp() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   4. WP->main() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:960
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   5. WP->parse_request() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:713
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   6. do_action_ref_array() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:373
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   7. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:515
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   8. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   9. WC_API->handle_api_requests() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  10. do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-api.php:97
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  11. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  12. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  13. WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway->check_ipn_response() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  14. do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway.php:1221
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  15. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  16. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  17. WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway->successful_request() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  18. WC_Woo_Mercado_Pago_Module::get_wc_status_for_mp_status() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway.php:1353
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: failed in /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/woocommerce-mercadopago.php on line 691
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/index.php:0
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   2. require() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/index.php:17
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   3. wp() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-blog-header.php:16
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   4. WP->main() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php:960
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   5. WP->parse_request() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:713
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   6. do_action_ref_array() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:373
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   7. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:515
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   8. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP   9. WC_API->handle_api_requests() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  10. do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-api.php:97
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  11. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  12. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  13. WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway->check_ipn_response() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  14. do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway.php:1221
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  15. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  16. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  17. WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway->successful_request() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 19:18:36 UTC] PHP  18. WC_Woo_Mercado_Pago_Module::get_wc_status_for_mp_status() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-mercadopago/includes/WC_WooMercadoPago_CustomGateway.php:1353
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/Core/vendor/todopago/php-sdk/TodoPago/lib/Client.php on line 5
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:0
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   2. do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php:214
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   3. WP_Hook->do_action() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php:453
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   4. WP_Hook->apply_filters() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   5. WC_Admin_Menus->settings_page_init() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:286
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   6. WooCommerce->payment_gateways() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-menus.php:90
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   7. WC_Payment_Gateways::instance() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-woocommerce.php:667
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   8. WC_Payment_Gateways->__construct() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php:43
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP   9. WC_Payment_Gateways->init() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php:70
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  10. WC_TodoPago_Gateway->__construct() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-payment-gateways.php:108
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  11. TodoPago\Core->__construct() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/index.php:165
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  12. spl_autoload_call() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/Core/Core.php:55
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  13. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/Core/Core.php:55
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  14. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/Core/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:301
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  15. include() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/Core/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:414
[19-Jul-2018 20:30:29 UTC] PHP  16. require_once() /home/suplementosjunin/public_html/wp-content/plugins/Plugin-WooCommerce-master/Core/vendor/todopago/php-sdk/TodoPago/lib/Sdk.php:4
```

Gracias

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema. En mi caso no me deja ingresar la cantidad de cuotas en el checkout y por eso no me deja seguir con el pago.
Probe cambiando de cuenta de mercadopago para descartar que sea problema de cuenta. Reinstale plugin e inclusive lo probé en otro servidor.
Hasta ahora no encuentro respuesta

Comment: Hola Santi, nosotros no somos el servicio técnico de Mercado Pago, sino una comunidad de preguntas & respuestas sobre programación. Si esto viene de algún código que hiciste, deberías compartir dicho código para que podamos intentar ayudarte... pero viendo el log que compartes, casi parece un fallo de la API de Mercado Pago y deberías ponerte en contacto con ellos directamente. Completa el [tour] para ver cómo funcionamos y lee [ask] para más información.